# Incorrect syntax near the keyword GROUP

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-update

I have the following update statement but I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

when executing.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[target_cumulative]
ON [dbo].[Appointments]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    UPDATE T1
    SET T1.[Target_Cumulative] = SUM(ISNULL(CAST([TARGET] AS FLOAT), 0))
    FROM dbo.Appointments AS T1
    INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON I.UniqueId = T1.UniqueId
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, T1.StartDate), T1.ResourceId;
END;
```

here is how my app looks like
[image]
What did I miss here?

Comment: Move group by above, assign alias and then do inner join.

Comment: @fiveelements i tried that but same error

Comment: You are doing SUM(TARGET) and doing group by on ResourceId and converted StartDate. Would you please explain your requirement? There are many ways you can achieve this however, group by at the end certainly is not fine. Better tyou post your data samples and the requirement clearly.

Comment: my requirements: i have a work order of a certain quantity, i want split the work order by hours also i want to track the qty by work order by day to avoid  over targeting or schedule sometime the work order qty is 30 but i schedule for 40 that means over target 10. For example: lets say i have a work order 123 of qty:30. now i want to split and schedule work order #123 as 8AM-9AM build 10 of 30, 9AM - 10Am build 10 and the rest 10 11AM -12PM. so i would like to sum(target) and get cumulative so that i know how much is work order qty and how much i target. i hope that's clear

Comment: i added an image how the app looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
create table appt (target int, target_cumulative int, unique_id int, resource_id int, start_date datetime);
create table inserted(unique_id int, value int);

insert into appt values(10, 0, 1, 1, '2019-07-26 08:00:00');
insert into appt values(20, 0, 2, 2, '2019-07-26 07:00:00');
insert into appt values(30, 0, 3, 1, '2019-07-26 10:00:00');
insert into appt values(10, 0, 4, 1, '2019-07-26 11:00:00');
insert into appt values(20, 0, 5, 2, '2019-07-26 09:00:00');

insert into inserted values(1, 10);
insert into inserted values(2, 10);
insert into inserted values(3, 10);
insert into inserted values(4, 10);
insert into inserted values(5, 10);

update appt set target_cumulative=xtarget
from (select t1.resource_id, sum(t1.target)as xtarget from appt t1
inner join inserted as i on t1.unique_id=i.unique_id
group by convert(date, t1.start_date), t1.resource_id) t2
where appt.resource_id=t2.resource_id;
```

Here is the fiddle you can check and modify as needed: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88d26c1814168079d555e6bc2e214daa)

Comment: yes that's exactly what  i'm looking for but how can apply your solution on my current tables using trigger

Comment: I have created the table structure just like yours: appt => appointments, inserted => inserted and column names also identical. I think you can easily map this to your query. Let me know if you have any specific issue.